# Get Products Belong to custom attribute id

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, graphql, mageplaza

I have added mageplaza brands to my magento project and I can get the list of brands that I have with following graphql

```
query getMpBrands {
  mpbrand(filter: {}, storeId: 1, currentPage: 1, pageSize: 20) {
    total_count
    items {
      attribute_id
      brand_id
      default_value
      description
      image
      is_featured
      meta_description
      meta_keywords
      meta_title
      option_id
      page_title
      short_description
      static_block
      store_id
      url_key
      value
    }
  }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "mpbrand": {
      "total_count": 6,
      "items": [
        {
          "attribute_id": 1134,
          "brand_id": 7,
          "default_value": "test 1",
          "description": "test-1",
          "image": "https://uatpwa.nominb2b.mn/media/mageplaza/brand/xiaomi_logo.png",
          "is_featured": 1,
          "meta_description": "test-1",
          "meta_keywords": "test-1",
          "meta_title": "test-1",
          "option_id": 11603,
          "page_title": "test-1",
          "short_description": "test-1",
          "static_block": null,
          "store_id": 1,
          "url_key": "test-1",
          "value": "test 1"
        },
        {
          "attribute_id": 1134,
          "brand_id": 8,
          "default_value": "test 2",
          "description": "test-2",
          "image": "https://uatpwa.nominb2b.mn/media/mageplaza/brand/lg_logo_2.png",
          "is_featured": 1,
          "meta_description": "test-2",
          "meta_keywords": "test-2",
          "meta_title": "test-2",
          "option_id": 11604,
          "page_title": "test-2",
          "short_description": "test-2",
          "static_block": null,
          "store_id": 1,
          "url_key": "test-2",
          "value": "test 2"
        },
        {
          "attribute_id": 1134,
          "brand_id": 9,
          "default_value": "test 3",
          "description": "test-3",
          "image": "https://uatpwa.nominb2b.mn/media/mageplaza/brand/casio_logo_4.png",
          "is_featured": 1,
          "meta_description": "test-3",
          "meta_keywords": "test-3",
          "meta_title": "test-3",
          "option_id": 11605,
          "page_title": "test-3",
          "short_description": "test-3",
          "static_block": null,
          "store_id": 1,
          "url_key": "test-3",
          "value": "test 3"
        },
        {
          "attribute_id": 1134,
          "brand_id": 10,
          "default_value": "test 4",
          "description": "test-4",
          "image": "https://uatpwa.nominb2b.mn/media/mageplaza/brand/the_north_face_2.png",
          "is_featured": 1,
          "meta_description": "test-4",
          "meta_keywords": "test-4",
          "meta_title": "test-4",
          "option_id": 11606,
          "page_title": "test-4",
          "short_description": "test-4",
          "static_block": null,
          "store_id": 1,
          "url_key": "test-4",
          "value": "test 4"
        },
        {
          "attribute_id": 1134,
          "brand_id": 11,
          "default_value": "test 5",
          "description": "test-5",
          "image": "https://uatpwa.nominb2b.mn/media/mageplaza/brand/xiaomi_logo_1.png",
          "is_featured": 1,
          "meta_description": "test-5",
          "meta_keywords": "test-5",
          "meta_title": "test-5",
          "option_id": 11607,
          "page_title": "test-5",
          "short_description": "test-5",
          "static_block": null,
          "store_id": 1,
          "url_key": "test-5",
          "value": "test 5"
        },
        {
          "attribute_id": 1134,
          "brand_id": 12,
          "default_value": "test 6",
          "description": "test-6",
          "image": "https://uatpwa.nominb2b.mn/media/mageplaza/brand/lg_logo_3.png",
          "is_featured": 1,
          "meta_description": "test-6",
          "meta_keywords": "test-6",
          "meta_title": "test-6",
          "option_id": 11608,
          "page_title": "test-6",
          "short_description": "test-6",
          "static_block": null,
          "store_id": 1,
          "url_key": "test-6",
          "value": "test 6"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the list of products that have the brand_id.Can I get the products by passing the brand_id?What is the graphql I can use.Please help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about GraphQL in Magento, but you should use the products query (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/queries/products.html) in order to get products and filter them by the brand_id. First of all, check if the result data contain the brand_id attribute, and if so, you can filter the products query using the filter attribute, eg:

```
{
  products(filter: { brand_id: { eq: "7" } }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      url_key
      stock_status
      price_range {
        minimum_price {
          regular_price {
            value
            currency
          }
        }
      }
    }
    total_count
    page_info {
      page_size
    }
  }
}
```